# how to enter into my win7 from rescue mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot, debian, grub

I have installed dual os :win7+debian7 on my pc.In the grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os { 
insmod part_msdos 
insmod ntfs 
set root='(hd0,msdos1)' 
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1A96148C96146B11 
chainloader +1
```

One day when i boot my pc ,there is a problem ,grub rescue > mode in the console.

How can i boot my pc in this situation?

Comment: past experience tells me there can be a number of reasons why it happenee, and how to fix. consider googling debian grub install from deb installer cd

Comment: how to write the debian grub install command?

Comment: from debian rescue prompt: $grub-install '(hd0)' ### that is simple case, assuming it detects your win partition correctly.

Comment: you may need to adjust the grub.cfg afterwards, but try the default first.